# How to mock a un-export (private) function inside user module using Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a "private" function which wraps the common functionality for an API request and I have a bunch of "public" functions to fire the actual requests with request configuration object (see below in `requestUploadStatementFile` file).

I am trying to test these public functions but I am not sure how to mock the private function using Jest, in this case, `requestWithAutoTokenRenew` function.

```
/**
 * An API wrapper which auto renew JTW once it get expired
 *
 * @param {Object} requestConfig Request configuration object
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
const requestWithAutoTokenRenew = async requestConfig => {
  const session = await doGetSession();
  const sessionToken = session.idToken.jwtToken;
  const { url, method, params, payload } = requestConfig;
  const requestObj = {
    url,
    method,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: sessionToken,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: payload,
    ...params
  };

  return axios.request(requestObj).then(response => response.data);
};

/**
 * Upload bank or credit card statement for parsing
 *
 * @param {Object} file Statement PDF file needs to be parsed
 */
export const requestUploadStatementFile = file => {
  const requestConfig = {
    url: URL_UPLOAD,
    method: "POST",
    payload: file
  };

  return requestWithAutoTokenRenew(requestConfig);
};
```

Comment: It is considered a bad practice to mock private function.
You should always mock only the outer layer of your app, usually public API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I adopted is not to mock the entire "private" function but **only** the "impossible" part of the functionality inside the “private” function. In this case, fetching the token from the remote service `doGetSession` and calling external API using Axios lib `request` method.

```
// Mocks
import { request } from "axios";
import { doGetSession } from "../utilities/auth/auth";

// Targets
import { requestUploadStatementFile } from "./api";

jest.mock("../utilities/auth/auth");
jest.mock("axios");

describe("requestUploadStatementFile", () => {
  it("should fire request with correct reqeust configuration object", done => {
    doGetSession.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      return Promise.resolve({ idToken: { jtwToken: "SAMPLE-TOKEN" } });
    });

    request.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      return Promise.resolve({ data: [] });
    });

    requestUploadStatementFile({}).then(transactions => {
      const transactionsExpected = [];
      const requestExpectedArgs = {
        data: {},
        headers: { Accept: "application/json", Authorization: undefined, "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://*.*.amazonaws.com/api/upload"
      };

      expect(transactions).toEqual(transactionsExpected);
      expect(request).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(request).toHaveBeenCalledWith(requestExpectedArgs);

      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks for the comment from @felixmosh.

> It is considered a bad practice to mock private function. You should always mock only the outer layer of your app, usually public API

Comment: I agree. Similarly, I mocked node-fetch call inside my private function (which function under test was using).